# Why does the text inside an <input> tag get cut off even if there's already a padding?

Tags: html, css

Ok so I found out that the text inside an `<input>` tag still gets cut off even though the `<input>` tag already has a padding. You'll notice it more when you set your font style to anything cursive.

Take a look at this image:
[image]

The first text box in the screenshot is an input of type=text and the second text box is just a div. The input text box cuts off the tail of character 'j', while the div text box does not.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" value="juvenescent" />
<div>juvenescent</div>
```

CSS:

```css
input, div {
  font-family: cursive;
  font-size: 2em;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

div {
  background-color: white;
}
```

Here is a link to the jsfiddle:
[https://jsfiddle.net/9eLzqszx](https://jsfiddle.net/9eLzqszx/)

What would be the workaround here? Obviously, I want the padding of the input text box to NOT cut the text inside it.

Comment: You'll need to include the font in your Fiddle.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a [**link to an example or site**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: I'm guessing that this is a `font-style:italic` issue where the font is not **actually** italic but rather browser faux-italic. We've seen this before, I'm sure.

Comment: Yeah, and those faux italics tend to be rendered outside of the text bounding rectangle sometimes - and those parts that are "sticking out" are then simply cut of in a case like this.

Comment: It's not the faux italics that causes the problem. It's how the text inside an input gets rendered.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It looks like the curve of the J goes past the left-hand side of what the browser considers to be the edge of the letter. Instead of using padding for both sides, use padding for top/right/bottom and instead use text-indent for the left, it should do the trick!

```css
input {
  font-family: cursive;
  font-size: 2em;
  padding: 15px 20px 15px 0;
  font-style:italic;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-indent: 20px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/will0220/pxrs321f/3/

Comment: I wouldn't add such a large value to `text-indent` because if the user writes a large text, the text will stick on the left side.

Comment: I personally kind of like that the text doesn't get cut off before the edge using this solution, but it's really just a matter of preference!

Comment: How can I solve this if the text is cut on the right side with `text-align: right`?

Answer (score 2):

An input element is a *special* element as it needs to cut and allow the user to navigate through its text. Its active text zone isn't increased by the padding, and that's why you're seeing this behavior. Firefox seems to be more clever than the bunch, as it doesn't vertically cut the text if the text's width is smaller than the input's active text zone.

A workaround would be to add `text-indent` and decrease `padding-left`:

```
text-indent: 5px;
padding-left: 15px; /* Originally 20px */
```

You can see it in a fiddle [over here](https://jsfiddle.net/9eLzqszx/5/).

Answer (score 1):

You could try increasing your line height property. That would be restricting the viewable area for the letters causing them to be cut off. However, that's probably a crappy hack if you want it to match the same size as your div.

Comment: The issue is the horizontal padding, not vertical padding.

Answer (score -1):

Add `height: auto;` to your input type=text to keep flexibility, and change the padding to get the original effect, like this padding: `14px 20px;`

Comment: The issue is the horizontal padding, not vertical padding.